# Antlr4 channels behavior

Tags: antlr4, behavior, channel

I have the following construct:

```
mode PASS_THROUGH;
    END_LITERAL: PASS_THROUGH_CHAR* '{/literal}'            -> popMode;
    PASS_THROUGH_CHAR: .+                                   -> channel( TEXT );
```

When this mode gets executed the END_LITERAL get all the PASS_THROUGH_CHARs pre-appended to it.
I would have though that all the PASS_THROUGH_CHAR would have been on the TEXT channel and END_LITERAL would have simply been '{/literal}

Is this behavior correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say why it behaved as you say, but the compound/conflicting use of * and + on and in PASS_THROUGH_CHAR is the root cause.  Below is what I think you were trying to accomplish.

```
START_LITERAL: '{/literal}'   -> pushMode(PASS_THROUGH);

mode PASS_THROUGH;
    END_LITERAL: '{/literal}'   -> popMode;
    PASS_THROUGH_CHAR: .        -> more, channel( TEXT );
```

Updated: 
I have not tried this exactly, but use of the 'more' option may (should) collapse each string of PASS_THROUGH_CHAR into a single token.

Comment: That creates the exact problem that I'm trying to avoid. If I process a 90K text file it puts each character into the channel as a single token not as a 90k text string. Doing this in C# requires about 7Gb of memory to resolve it and takes about 15 seconds to process it. If I do it the way I have, it only takes a second or two and only uses about 3MB of memory, but unfortunately it puts it all the PASS_THROUGH_CHARS into END_LITERAL token.

Comment: I am not familiar specifically with the C# backend, but that level of performance is surprising.  Have you done a Lexer unit test of just your START_LITERAL rule and this mode? A Lexer production of 90k tokens is not that unusual.  Are your tokens 'heavy'?  Instrument your TokenFactory to check for a token allocation/C# backend problem.  Is it possible that the backend is putting a copy, rather than a reference to the input stream in each token?  The math almost works.  Also, the lexer will run to completion before the parser really starts, so what fraction of the 15s is spent in the lexer?

Comment: All the processing time and memory are taken up by the lexer. I can set a breakpoint in the parser and it take at least 15 seconds before it hits the breakpoint. What the size each token is I have no idea on how to find out as it's almost impossible to find the runtime size of a reference item let alone and item attached to an interface (IToken). Tried implementing a TokenFactory but didn't really show much. I have logged it as a bug. See what happens.